# one way UDP communication

Tags: python, sockets, udp

I am trying to establish UDP conection between 2 of my computers (1 and 2).
I succeeded in establish UDP connection in which computer 1 is the client ("sending") and computer 2 is the server ("reciving").

Now I am trying to do the opposite: I want computer 2 to be the client and computer 1 to be the server. I am using the same programs as I have written before, however it doesn't work.

When I use Wireshark, I can see the sended messeges from computer 2, however the python doesn't recive them...

Any Ideas?

here is my code:

client:

```
import socket

IP_robot    = '127.0.0.1'
port_robot  = 8830

def send_data(V,IP,port):
    my_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    my_socket.connect((IP,port))

    MESSAGE=str(V)
    my_socket.send(MESSAGE)

    my_socket.close

V="123456"
send_data(V,IP_robot,port_robot)
```

where in my program IP_robot is the IP of the server.

server:

```
import socket

IP_commands = "0.0.0.0"
port_commands = 8830

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
sock.bind((IP_commands, port_commands))

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes 
    print data
```

**edit:**
I have tried to use TCP and it still dosent work. It seemes that one of my computers refuses to recive it's messges in python... any sugesstions?

Comment: perhaps port 8830 is open on computer 2 but closed on computer 1 ?

Comment: does it throw an exception when calling `sock.bind`? Did you try using other ports? Maybe use a specific address instead of the "bind to all" 0.0.0.0

Comment: smoggers: thanks for the answer... I have checked with some other ports and it still doesn't work, so I dont think this is the problem...

Comment: TryToSolveSimple: it dosent throw an exception when I am running the program. I have try to use a specific address and it throw: 'return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 10049] The requested address is not valid in its context' 8-(

Comment: Try disabling the firewall on computer 1, if it has one enabled.

Comment: this is it! disabling the firewall... thankes Jeremy Friesner